# Is there a way to export a custom Menu containing macro in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Currently, I am working on a project using the VBA language on Excel, I have coded some macros and userforms, and to facilitate the exploitation for user, I customize the ribbon by integrating a new menu with the features of macros coded via VBA.

On my session, the program works well, however, when another user opens the file on his session, first the menu is not displayed and it is no longer available, I tried to export the menu, then I import it in the user's Excel file but unfortunately the result is negative. I would like to know if someone could help me solve this problem.

[image: #vba]

Comment: Welcome to SO. *customize the ribbon by integrating a new menu with the features of macros coded via VBA* How you call this menu? If you are doing it from personal macro workbook, you need to change the personal macro workbook of that user. IF not, make sure all macros are enabled and not blocked by default. Check Trust Center.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using CustomUI, not manual customization: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm

Comment: I've tried to use it, but the problem i that my macros are on Excel file VBA !